# Cannot install tensorflow-macos from conda miniforge?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As title, I've installed `miniforge3` with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and try using it to create a virtual environment with `tensorflow-macos` package, which can be found from the pypi website: [search result](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-macos/). I have tried three different python versions `3.8.12`, `3.9.10`, `3.10.2` and have `.condarc` as follow:

```
channels: [apple, conda-forge, pypi]
auto_activate_base: false
```

the error all the same:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-macos
```

Can anyone explain why the package `tensorflow-macos` can be found on pypi but I still cannot install it by conda with pypi channel added?

Comment: This seems relevant: [Installation on conda](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos#installation-on-conda) in the README of the library repository

Comment: @aaossa: thanks, I just read through the long issue linked in the section but it doesn't answer my last question...

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow it difficult even under native Linux operating systems (Ubuntu YECH!).  I would suggest you dual-boot into a Linux distro of your choice and setup Docker for a simple solution... unless you REALLY want to endure pain.

Here is the documentation from NVidia: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker

Docker makes this stuff a lot easier!

Comment: Upvote because of docker. But sadly my macOS only has AMD GPU...

Comment: Only Linux Docker containers are currently supported by NVidia Cuda!

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker

Answer (score 1):

Since `tensorflow-macos` is platform specific it's no need to install it via `conda` `miniforge3` channel for compatibility, just follow the guide from [Apple's tensorflow-metal PluggableDevice guide](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to further utilize your M1(or AMD) GPU.

Notice that you **have to** use python `3.8.x` to run the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow-macos tensorflow-metal
```